# Ruby/Rails - Remove text inside parentheses from a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

If data that is returned in the following way:

1. The Matrix (1999)
2. Shawshank Redemption (1994)

Just wondering whether there's an easy way to remove the year and parentheses from the string e.g. remove (1999)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean given **The Matrix (1999)** as input and return just **1999**?

Comment: @LimboPeng Nope, I mean given **The Matrix (1999)** as input and return just **The Matrix**

Comment: If the strings are all in the form of `MovieName (Year)`, you can do it with regexp.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As long as nested parenthesis aren't an issue, you can simply use a regular expression:

```
text.sub /\s*\(.+\)$/, ''
```

`sub` replaces everything matched by the expression with the given string, in this case an empty string (nothing).

- `\s*` include any number of whitespace characters before the open parenthesis
- `\(` open parenthesis as a literal
- `.+` match one or more of any characters
- `\)` close parenthesis as a literal
- `$` match end of string - optional, you can leave this out if you want to remove parenthesized text anywhere in the string

Comment: Just to be sure: no need to use `gsub`?

Comment: @Limbo `sub` will perform the replacement only once, `gsub` will perform as many times as possible. Unless you expect multiple parenthesized sections at the end of the string, you won't need `gsub`.

Comment: What happens if the movie title is, say, "Pancakes (2000)", then you'd be dealing with things like "Pancakes (2000) (2012)" and you'd chop off too much.

Comment: @muistooshort Yes, that's true. You can avoid taking out multiple brackets by replacing the `.+` with `[^\)]+` to specify that there shouldn't be any additional close parenthesis characters inside of the matched ones.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
text = "The Matrix (1999)"

text[0..(text.rindex("(") - 1)]
```

Comment: What happens when I release my "Pancakes (2000)" movie this summer? Then you'd be parsing `'Pancakes (2000) (2012)'`...

Comment: Hi @muistooshort, "Pancakes (2000)", will display "Pancakes", but yes you are right, this will work only to the following format text1 (<taxt2>) will return text1, this was just a quick solution :D

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

text = "The Matrix (2022) (test wed 11: 57)"

step:1
text.gsub(/(.*?)/, '')

Out put: "The Matrix"

step:2
text.gsub(/(test.*?)/, '')

Out put: "The Matrix (2002)"

step:2
text[text.rindex('(')..text.rindex(')')]

Out put: "(test wed 11: 57)"